# Why doesn't this .equals() work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, equals

I'm working in Eclipse (Android). In the following blocks, EmployeeInt and RestaurantInt are data types and query() opens a connection to the database and parses the results. When I print the query results, I get identical strings, but the boolean is still false. I've tried trimming the strings, but that didn't help.

```
public boolean verifyEmployee(String email, String password) {
    ArrayList<EmployeeInt> employeeEmailID = query("SELECT employeeID FROM employees WHERE emailAddress = \'"+email+"\'");
    ArrayList<EmployeeInt> employeePasswordID = query("SELECT employeeID FROM employees WHERE password = \'"+password+"\'");
    String stringEmployeeEmailID = employeeEmailID.toString();
    String stringEmployeePasswordID = employeePasswordID.toString();

    if(stringEmployeeEmailID.equals(stringEmployeePasswordID)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Executing the above gives me false, while executing the following block (virtually identical) gives me true.

```
public boolean verifyRestaurant(String email, String password) {
    ArrayList<RestaurantInt> restaurantEmailID = query("SELECT restaurantID FROM restaurants WHERE emailAddress = \'"+email+"\'");
    ArrayList<RestaurantInt> restaurantPasswordID = query("SELECT restaurantID FROM restaurants WHERE password = \'"+password+"\'");
    String stringRestaurantEmailID = restaurantEmailID.toString();
    String stringRestaurantPasswordID = restaurantPasswordID.toString();

    if(stringRestaurantEmailID.equals(stringRestaurantPasswordID)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out my mistake?

***EDIT***

I changed it to this and it worked:

```
public boolean verifyEmployee(String email, String password) {
    ArrayList<EmployeeInt> employeeEmailID = query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emailAddress = \'"+email+"\'");
    ArrayList<EmployeeInt> employeePasswordID = query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE password = \'"+password+"\'");
    int intEmployeeEmailID = employeeEmailID.get(0).getID();
    int intEmployeePasswordID = employeePasswordID.get(0).getID();

    if(intEmployeeEmailID==intEmployeePasswordID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know I could also use return (condition), but I would like to add some messages if the login fails, something like:

```
System.err.println("email address and password do not correspond");
```

I'm not making an app to publish, it's merely for an assignment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why are you converting `ArrayList` to `String` for comparison? And also, can you show us the contents of `ArrayLists` in both the cases?

Comment: To debug the problem, you could check `stringEmployeeEmailID` and `stringEmployeePasswordID` before comparing to track down the problem.  In general, this authentication method is not well designed as it may fail if two employees use the same e-mail adress or the same password.

Comment: + don't use `if(condition) { return true;} else {return false;}`. You can simply do `return (condition);`

Comment: If you show two code blocks that are "virtually identical" it would be a nice gesture to point out where exactly they differ, rather than to let everyone find out by themselves...

Comment: @Heuster the only difference is that in the first block, it's regarding employees, whereas in the second block, it's regarding restaurants

Comment: @Deeyennay the code you are using is making 2 queries to the database when you could just add an `and password = \'"+password+"\'"` - another thing is that you should make queries like that parameterized so that they are escaped in the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` on an `ArrayList`. Two different `ArrayList` objects will return two different `toString()` strings. You probably meant to get the first element of the ArrayList, and convert THAT to a string.

**Example**

`EmployeeInt` is your custom object. In my example, I assume it has some `int` field that can be retreived with `getID()`.

```
ArrayList<EmployeeInt> idList = query("SELECT employeeID FROM employees WHERE emailAddress = \'"+email+"\'");
int ID = idList.get(0).getID();
stringEmployeeEmailID = String.valueOf(ID);
```

This may be easier to read than code:

- `query()` returns an `ArrayList`
- We extract the first element of the `ArrayList` - this is the part you left out
- We get the ID of that element
- We convert it to a String

Comment: That was my initial assumption/recommendation at first as well, but it seems that toString would work in this case as well. https://ideone.com/gTC9vY

Comment: @dberm22 You got lucky, because ArrayList's toString just happens to print the contents of the underlying array. You hardcoded the contents to be exactly the same, so you got a positive result.

Comment: Correct, but he is using an ArrayList as well. Regardless of how you get the ArrayLists, if the contents match, it should return true. Agreed this is not the best way to do it, but it does work.

Comment: This worked for me. Do you know why the second block worked with toString though?

Comment: @dberm22 He also got lucky in one case, but not in the other case. Wait for my edit and I'll explain why. It's a rather long edit. Just to be clear, comparing ArrayLists did NOT work in one of his cases, so you must be wrong.

Comment: @Deeyennay, the implementation of `EmployeeInt`/`RestaurantInt` (in particular, their `toString` methods) would be my first guess.

Comment: @BrianS...good point. If they were normal Integers, the OP's method would always work.

Comment: @dberm22 Actually, I just found myself wondering why the OP didn't query for the password and the email in the same query, and I'm now unable to edit my question. Why would one write two queries when both parameters are immediately available and they are in the SAME TABLE?